# how i can use pip3 or github source in my github project for openshift?

Tags: git, python-3.x, github, pip, git-submodules

I tried to clone GitHub project ([this](https://github.com/dimka665/vk)), and added it to my project. So, I can see this in my repository, but when I try to run it on openshift I get `error: build error: No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'vk'`. What did I make wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is that you simply copied this project to subdirectory of your project, instead of using [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). i.e. `git submodule add <repo>`

Comment: Great. I created an answer to your question instead of just comment. Please consider upvoting or accepting that answer if you think it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you simply copied [dimka665/vk](https://github.com/dimka665/vk) project into subdirectory of your project, instead of creating a submodule of your project using git submodule.

You can add that project as a submodule using:

```
git submodule add git@github.com:dimka665/vk.git
```

Answer (score 1):

The project you've mentioned is [at PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vk) so you can install it with simple command

```
pip3 install vk
```

Add "vk" to your requirements (`requirements.txt` or `setup.py`) instead of copying the repo to your project.

You can install directly from Github:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/dimka665/vk.git#egg=vk
```

`git+https://github.com/dimka665/vk.git#egg=vk` is the requirement you can use.

Comment: But how can i do it on openshift? I can't find a command line or something like it there